# Strange thing using jQuery progressbar

Tags: jquery-ui, colors, jquery-ui-progressbar

I'm trying to use just a single color in jQuery progressbar, but it fill the whole div.

Here's the problem, i just use these functions.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#progressbar").css({ "background": '#FF0000' });
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({  value: 10  });    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtf7M/1/

How do i make this fill properly, step by step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS file is missing. Add http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css to your resources and it will be ok.

Edit:

If you don't want to load whole CSS file, just add this code in your page http://jsfiddle.net/jtf7M/21/:

```
<style>
    .ui-progressbar { height:2em; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; }
    .ui-progressbar .ui-progressbar-value {margin: -1px; height:100%; }
    .ui-widget-content {
        border: 1px solid #AAA;
        background: white;
    }
    .ui-corner-all {
        -moz-border-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
        -khtml-border-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
        border-radius: 4px/*{cornerRadius}*/;
    }
    .ui-widget-header {
        border: 1px solid #AAA/*{borderColorHeader}*/;
        background: #CCC;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Oh thx, it works. But, do you know some way to make this work without using jquery-ui css?

Comment: You can add your own css if you don't want to load jquery-ui-css.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no jQuery ui lib load on that jsfiddle. 
But you are doing right.

http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#animated